# Template specialization with a specific templated class

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following simple C++ class:

```
using namespace std;

template<class T1>
class ValueWrapper {
private:
    T1 value_;

public:
    ValueWrapper() {} 
    ValueWrapper(const T1& value) {
        value_ = value;     
    }

    ValueWrapper(const ValueWrapper<T1> &wrapper) {
        value_ = wrapper.value_;
    }

    ValueWrapper& Set(const T1& value) {
        value_ = value;
        return *this;
    }

    T1 Get() const {
        return value_;
    }
};
```

I was trying to create a simple `shared_ptr` wrapper for that class (ultimately allowing the developer to use the class without the dereferencing operator if desired). While I've seen a few examples of wrapping a `shared_ptr`, I couldn't find any that also used a specialization for a templated class.

Using the class above, I created a `ValueShared` class which derives from `shared_ptr`:

```
template<class T1>
class ValueShared : public shared_ptr<T1> {
public:
    ValueShared& operator =(const T1& rhs) {
        // nothing to do in base
    return *this;
    }
};
```

Then, I created a custom `make_shared_value` function:

```
//
// TEMPLATE FUNCTION make_shared
template<class T1, class... Types> inline
ValueShared<T1> make_shared_value(Types&&... Arguments)
{   // make a shared_ptr
    _Ref_count_obj<T1> *_Rx = new _Ref_count_obj<T1>(_STD forward<Types>(Arguments)...);

    ValueShared<T1> _Ret;
    _Ret._Resetp0(_Rx->_Getptr(), _Rx);
    return (_Ret);
}
```

**But, here's the problem code:**

```
template<class T1, class ValueWrapper<T1>> 
class ValueShared<ValueWrapper<T1>> : public shared_ptr<ValueWrapper<T1>>{
    public:
        ValueShared& operator =(const ValueWrapper<T1>& rhs) {              
            auto self = this->get();
            self.Set(rhs->Get());
            return *this;
        }
};
```

I wanted to provide a specialization of the `equals operator` here that was specialized to the ValueWrapper class (so that it would Get/Set the value from the right hand side value).

I've tried a few things, but the current error is:

```
error C2943: 'ValueWrapper<T1>' : template-class-id redefined
as a type argument of a template
```

Maybe this isn't the proper approach, or maybe it's not possible?

Comment: `template<class T1, class ValueWrapper<T1>>` => `template<class T1, class V1 = ValueWrapper<T1>>`. Actually, do you even need Value Wrapper as template arg?

Comment: What version of microsoft C++ compiler are you using? It should work with the latest version (v120 or v120 CTP_Nov2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should remove your error:

```
template<class T1>
class ValueShared<ValueWrapper<T1>> : public shared_ptr<ValueWrapper<T1>> {
    public:
        ValueShared& operator =(const ValueWrapper<T1>& rhs)
        {
            auto self = this->get();
            self->Set(rhs.Get());
            return *this;
        }
};
```

Comment: I assume `TWrappedType` should have been `T1`. And now that the one error was fixed, I also needed to modify the function body: `self->Set(rhs.Get())`.